# Why do I get a different histogram in ggplot2 when the levels of the factors are re-ordered?

Tags: r, ggplot2, histogram

Why do I get different histograms depending on the order of the factor in the data?

```
# First histogram
# [Get data from here: https://github.com/TarekDib03/ExploratoryDataAnalysisCoursera/blob/master/maacs.Rda
# - click 'view raw']
load("maacs.Rda")
# ggplot
ggplot(data = maacs, aes(log(eno), fill = mopos))+
geom_histogram()+
scale_fill_manual(values=c("red", "blue"))

# Second histogram
load("maacs.Rda")
# Change order of yes/no levels
maacs$mopos <- factor(maacs$mopos, levels = c("yes", "no")) 
# ggplot
ggplot(data = maacs, aes(log(eno), fill = mopos))+
  geom_histogram()+
  scale_fill_manual(values=c("blue", "red"))
```

The means are correct - the "yes" group should be higher than the "no" group. But the counts are really different.

It might be easier to see with this simple example:

```
set.seed(10)
n <- 100
x <- data.frame(A = c(rnorm(n, 5, 2), rnorm(n, 10, 2)), 
           B = c(rep("yes", n), rep("no", n)))

ggplot(data = x, aes(x = A, fill = B))+
  geom_histogram()+
  scale_fill_manual(values=c("blue", "red"))

# Re-order levels:
x$B <- factor(x$B, levels = c("yes", "no")) 

# Plot again
ggplot(data = x, aes(x = A, fill = B))+
  geom_histogram()+
  scale_fill_manual(values=c("red", "blue"))
```

The groups have become 'mixed up' where I've circled:

[image: First histogram]

[image: Second histogram]

Thanks!

Comment: They are actually the same, but just stacked in a different order - blue on top in the first chart, red on top in the second.

Comment: I can not reproduce this behavior. Getting result as expected. Try updating ggplot2, restarting R.